# UIWebView loading errors

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uikit, core-graphics, javax.imageio

Whenever I load a page in a UIWebView i get this error in the console

```
ImageIO: <ERROR> _CGImagePluginInitGIFmalformed GIF file (1005 x 767)
```

It's logged several times, but doesn't seem to effect anything as the page loads as expected.

Here's the code that I'm using to load the page:

```
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[webView setDelegate:self];
```

Any ideas what this error means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not to answer, as it comes from the deepest parts of CGImage. I have noticed this error myself several times in the simulator. As you have noticed, I can confirm that it doesn't do anything. Everything looks as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You must check HTML file that you load.Post It! The snippet of code doesn't have error..

Comment: I also noticed that the error only occurs in the Simulator not on the actual device, so I guess it's not really a problem.

Comment: The error message comes from ImageIO and is about GIF data, so I don't think the HTML is the problem.